# Join columns from different query

Tags: sql-server, select, while-loop

I want to do the same query using a variable at the where condition from 0 to 24 and join the results at the same column.

```
DECLARE @x AS INT
SET @x = 0

WHILE @x < 24
BEGIN
    SELECT @x, COUNT(trans_num) 
    FROM [RealTimeVending].[dbo].[rtv_transactions] 
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE, trans_date) >= '2018-03-28' 
      AND DATEPART(HH, trans_date) = @x 
      AND cliente_id = 13 
    GROUP BY cliente_id

    SET @x = @x + 1
END
```

This is what I get :

[image]

The problem with my solution is that I have different querys and I want the results at the same column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSK's answer is dead on. A minor variation to that to avoid duplicating the  DATEPART function is to use a sub-query. Note that I also removed the conversion of trans_date to date portion as it is redundant. You can directly compare the time to the date which will yield a faster query also.

```
SELECT t.Hour, COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM (
   SELECT
      DATEPART(HH,trans_date) AS Hour
   FROM [RealTimeVending].[dbo].[rtv_transactions] 
   WHERE 
      trans_date >= '2018-03-28' 
      AND cliente_id = 13
) AS t
GROUP BY Hour
ORDER BY Hour
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a while loop for the required output, following simple query should give you desired output.

```
SELECT COUNT(trans_num), DATEPART(HH,trans_date)
 FROM [RealTimeVending].[dbo].[rtv_transactions] 
  where convert(date,trans_date) >= '2018-03-28' 
  and cliente_id=13
GROUP BY DATEPART(HH,trans_date)
ORDER BY DATEPART(HH,trans_date)
```

If you are fetching the data for a single client `cliente_id=13`, in that case you don't need to put `group by client_id`. It will only be required if you fetching the data for multiple clients.

Comment: @ZoharPeled True :) thanks for pointing this, I removed it from the answer.